# Unable to change xib file orientation in xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, xib

I have a certain xib file which i would like to set constraints to.
Adding portrait constraints are no problem, But when i try to rotate the xib file, reorder the view and set new landscape constraints, Xcode won't rotate the xib, and it's impossible to create landscape constraints in portrait mode.

Any help?

Adding some screen shots:

1) Orientation set to landscape
[image]

2) What i want to get (roughly):

[image]

Comment: There used to be a "Use Size Classes" tab which they have removed in XCode8. I thought you may not have checked it. But I guess, in your case its just an Xcode bug. Quit the XCode and try it once again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using `Size` in `FreeForm` so you need to change that to inferred then the controls to change to landscape works, i will post some images

[image]
[image]

Hope this help